# ng-repeat with ng-include not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-include

I am trying to use an `ng-repeat` that includes an `ng-include`. The problem is that the first element in the ng-repeat is just the `ng-include` template with none of the data from the `ng-repeat` filled in. Is there a way I can somehow bind the template from the `ng-include` so it works on the first `ng-repeat`?

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <div ng-include src="'views/template.html'"></div>
</div>
```

For example, if my `ng-repeat` contains 10 items, then the first item that is rendered will just be the empty template. Items 2-10 WILL be rendered as they should be. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: and you can't place ng-repeat into the template then do this?

Comment: There is no difference between first and other iteration. See you content for items array. The problem may be there.

Comment: try this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14112663/angularjs-ng-repeat-with-ng-include-not-rendering

Comment: I tried placing the ng-repeat inside the included template, but that didn't work. It just shows me the empty template. The ng-repeat inside the template is ignored.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First make sure that the data that is contained in the first index of items actually has the data that you want.

One possible solution to your problem would be to simply not show the first index of the ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-show="!$first">
   <div ng-include src="'views/template.html'"></div>
</div>
```

This may not actually tackle the root of your problem, but it may still get your application working a bit more like what you expect.

---

Another possible solution:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items" ng-include="'views/template.html'"></div>
```

see example here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yvd73HiFS8dXvpvpEeFu?p=preview

---

One more possible fix just for good measure:

Use a component:

html:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
   <my-include></my-include>
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module("app").directive("myInclude", function() {
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: "/views/template.html"
}
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. It seems that it works when I navigate to the page by clicking on a "link" using ``$location.path(route);``. However, once on the page, if I click refresh, then I have the original issue where the first item in the ng-repeat isn't filled in (none of the tags in the first item are filled in).

Comment: @RomainFournereau I disagree. http://plnkr.co/edit/uBbXMlI5MYEcjIfXXeQT?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, and finally figured out that the first element has not been fetched and compiled in time for the first `ng-repeat` iteration. Using `$templateCache` will fix the problem.

---

You can cache your template in a script tag:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="templateId.html">
    <p>This is the content of the template</p>
</script>
```

---

Or in your app's run function:

```
angular.module("app").run(function($http, $templateCache) {
    $http.get("/views/template.html", { cache: $templateCache });
});
```

---

You can also use `$templateCache` inside your directive, although it's a bit harder to setup. If your templates are dynamic, I would recommend creating a template cache service. This SO question has some good examples of template caching inside a directive and a service:

[Using $http and $templateCache from within a directive doesn't return results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171535/using-http-and-templatecache-from-within-a-directive-doesnt-return-results)

Comment: I am finding that $first and $last are always evaluating true for me on all repeated scopes - do you think your issue is related to mine ? Also $middle and $index is working fine - so I am using the scope variables correctly - anyone else ?

Answer (score 1):

Using a directive worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24673257/188926

In your case:

1) define a directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('mytemplate', function() {
    return {
      templateUrl: 'views/template.html'
    };
  });
```

2) use your new directive:

```
<mytemplate />
```

... or if you're [concerned](http://www.jeremyzerr.com/angularjs-directive-best-practices) about HTML validation:

```
<div mytemplate></div>
```